# How to get the contents of an associative array returned by pdo into an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I am using PHO PDO and getting it to return an associative array.

I can loop through the associative array created by PDO, but I cant work out how to return the array from a function.

```
function wantedrentals($provence, $country, $dbh)
   {
      echo "Now in wanted wanted rentals function<br><br>"; 

      $journeyrentalssarray = array();

      $sth = $dbh->query("SELECT summary, url, provence, country from tblAccomadation WHERE country = $country ");

    # setting the fetch mode
    $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    while($row = $sth->fetch()) 
        {
            echo $row['summary'] . "\n";
            echo $row['url'] . "\n";
            echo $row['provence'] . "\n";
            echo $row['country'] . "\n";
        }

  return $journeyrentalssarray;
  }
```

I am very new to PHP and PDO and would appreciate any help.

Comment: what you are getting for `var_dump( $row );` ?

Comment: You may want to look at this: [PDOStatement::fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php). This function returns the whole result as an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
function wantedrentals($provence, $country, $dbh)
   {
      echo "Now in wanted wanted rentals function<br><br>"; 

      $journeyrentalssarray = array();

      $sth = $dbh->query("SELECT summary, url, provence, country from     tblAccomadation WHERE country = '$country' ");

    # setting the fetch mode
    $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    while($row = $sth->fetch()) 
        {
            $journeyrentalssarray[] = $row; // add $row to $journeyrentalssarray array
            echo $row['summary'] . "\n";
            echo $row['url'] . "\n";
            echo $row['provence'] . "\n";
            echo $row['country'] . "\n";
        }

  return $journeyrentalssarray;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. If the posted solution does work for you you should mark it as "Solution" to award points for the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You may want it this way

```
function wantedrentals($provence, $country, $dbh)
   {
      echo "Now in wanted wanted rentals function<br><br>"; 

      $journeyrentalssarray = array();

      $sth = $dbh->query("SELECT summary, url, provence, country from tblAccomadation WHERE country = $country ");

    # setting the fetch mode
    //$sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  }
```

**PDO::FETCH_ASSOC** will returns an **array** indexed by column name as returned in your result set.

The return value of fetch function on success depends on the fetch type  in your case its FETCH_ASSOC and FALSE is returned on failure.

For more information please read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

We can also use fetchAll to get an array of  all of the result set rows.
So the function may look like this.

```
function wantedrentals($provence, $country, $dbh)
       {
          echo "Now in wanted wanted rentals function<br><br>"; 

          $journeyrentalssarray = array();

          $sth = $dbh->query("SELECT summary, url, provence, country from tblAccomadation WHERE country = $country ");


        return $sth-> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      }
```

For more information please read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Comment: This will only return 1 row and then stop.

Comment: Does it helps you? :D